# Usage of eclipse "org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have implemented my custom shortcut.
It is working fine, when I execute it via context menu from project explorer or from the menu run launcher.
It is not working when I execute it via CTRL+F11, meant this command was called `org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunLast`
As I debugged so far, this returns an empty list, which it should not.

org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchShortcutExtension.getAssociatedConfigurationTypes():

```java
 public Set<String> getAssociatedConfigurationTypes() {
     if(fAssociatedTypes == null) {
         fAssociatedTypes = new HashSet<>();
         IConfigurationElement[] children = fConfig.getChildren(IConfigurationElementConstants.CONFIGURATION_TYPES);
         String id = null;
         for (IConfigurationElement child : children) {
             id = child.getAttribute(IConfigurationElementConstants.ID);
             if(id != null) {
                 fAssociatedTypes.add(id);
             }
         }
     }
     return fAssociatedTypes;
 }
```

```xml
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchShortcuts">
     <shortcut
         class="com.my.LigthlyShortcut"
         id="com.my.LigthlyShortcut"
         label="Lightly Launch"
         modes="run">
         <contextualLaunch>
             <enablement>
                 <with
                     variable="selection">
                     <count
                         value="1">
                     </count>
                   <iterate operator="and">
                     <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile">
                         <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.extension"
                         value="lightly">
                         </test>
                    </adapt>
                 </iterate>
                 </with>
             </enablement>
         </contextualLaunch>
     </shortcut>
  </extension>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That code is looking for a `configurationType` element in the extension point which you haven't specified.

Comment: yes thx, missed `configurationType`